# How do I show percentage of tables without comments?

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote a query

```
SELECT COUNT(c_all.table_comment) / COUNT(c_target.table_comment)
FROM (
    SELECT table_comment
    FROM (
        SELECT table_comment
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        ) AS c_all
    WHERE table_comment <> ''
    ) AS c_target;
```

But it gives me error

> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'c_all.table_comment' in 'field list'

This is because scope of `c_all` alias is not global, just inside `()`.

How to rewrite query correctly?

Comment: Please add the DDL

Comment: I think question is clear without it and maybe even more general. Imagine that you have column where empty or non-empty string could be stored and you need to count percentage of rows with empty string in target column. I know how to do it with any programming language. But is it possible with native SQL ?

Answer (score 2):

This should solve your problem:

```
select sum(case when table_comment <> '' then 1 else 0 end) / count(*)
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

It will return percentage of non-empty comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN table_comment <> '' THEN 1 END)/count(1) 
total_comments_percentage 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```

Answer (score 0):

And yet another way is to rely on count()'s innate ability to not count NULLS; and simply substitute the '' for null...

[Demo](https://rextester.com/EAPB59382)

```
SELECT count(case when table_Comment = '' then null else table_Comment end) /
       count(table_Comment) as PercentEmpty
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;
```